# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Crashlytics", referenced from: objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Crashlytics", referenced from:       objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o

I tried updating Crashlytics (3.3.4) and have to update Fabric as well but there is some problem with the latest updates.

I don't know what is going on here.

Answer (score 3):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cocoapods/-Rsf5IXN0aM

I used the changes mentioned in the URL and downgraded the framework version and voila it is working fine but need to know on the latest version.